# Change content type for RabbitMQ Spring Cloud Stream Starter App

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

The documentation for the [Spring Cloud Stream Starter Apps](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/docs/Celsius.RELEASE/reference/html/sources.html#spring-cloud-stream-modules-http-source) for the RabbitMQ Source app lists several possible content types, each with a different resulting type for the output payload. However, it doesn't say how to choose which one you want to use. I'm deploying a Spring Cloud Data Flow connecting the Rabbit source to a Log sink, and all I get is the byte array. Even when I explicitly set the content type to "text/plain" in the Rabbit message's header, it shows up in the log sink as a byte array payload with headers: "contentType=application/octet-stream, originalContentType=text/plain".

I've got a vague idea that the answer is to set spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.content-type to the content type I want the Rabbit source to output, but I don't know where to put this setting within the Spring Cloud Data Flow. I'm new at this, and extremely confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass Spring Cloud Stream properties in Spring Cloud Data Flow via deployment properties.

You can find more information on this [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#passing_producer_consumer_properties)

Comment: Greg, there were some changes and improvements to content-type negotiations both in spring-amqp, rabbit-binder as well as spring-cloud-stream and what you are trying to achieve is definitely accomplishable, however it would greatly help if you could tell us what version of spring-cloud-stream you are currently using.

Comment: Well, I can tell you that I'm using the starter app  maven://org.springframework.cloud.stream.app:http-source-rabbit:1.3.0.RELEASE. I'm registering that into spring-cloud-dataflow-server-local-1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar. I'll probably have to back the Data Flow server to 1.2.3 though, unless a 1.3 release version comes out soon.

Comment: In any case, IG's pointer gave me enough information to go on. The SPDF console app prompts for deployment properties when deploying a stream, but it wouldn't accept spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.content-type. IG's link suggested the property should be prefixed with "app" and the application name, so: app.rabbit.spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.content-type=text/plain did the trick!