# Spring Cloud Stream router app

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I've been playing with the [router sink](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/router) in the Spring Cloud Stream App Starters, and I have a question about content type.

I'm sending a JSON string to the router, and I would like to write a SpEL expression to determine the routing. However, even when I run this by modifying the JUnit test cases in the project, the "payload" shows up as a string, not parsed JSON. When running JUnit test case for the filter processor, also in the Spring Cloud Stream App Starters, all I need to do is pass valid JSON in a string, and the payload is a LinkedHashMap. (A regular string, like "Hello, world!" makes the payload show up as a String type.)

I really want my router to have a HashMap payload as well. Otherwise, I can't figure out how to write my SpEL expression. I learned earlier how to [set a content type on Spring Cloud Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47850895/change-content-type-for-rabbitmq-spring-cloud-stream-starter-app), and so when I deploy the router in Spring Cloud Dataflow, I try to set it via:

```
stream deploy --name router-flow --properties "app.router.spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.content-type=application/json"
```

However, the payload stills shows up a string. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using the [#jsonPath SpEL function](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/spel.html#spel-functions) ? It's automatically registered in Stream apps.

Comment: Thanks! That did it for me! I really appreciate it. If you want to put move it into an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`#jsonPath()` SpEL function](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/spel.html#spel-functions) - it's automatically registered for use by Stream apps.